# Unable to change the text jquery ajax function?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

What is wrong with the following code? the `before` text should be changed to the content of `result`.however, I am able to get the alert message with `result`.

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#target').submit(function(){
              $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "hello.txt",
                async:true,
                success: function(result){
                  alert(result);
                  $('#after').text(result);
                }
              });
            });
        });
    </script>
        <title>strange</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="target" method= "get">
     bus number: <input type="text" name="bus"><br>      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>   
    <div id="after">before</div>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't prevent the default action of the `submit` event. On `submit` event the alert modal is shown and then the page is refreshed. Now, the element has the initial text content.

```
$('#target').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({...});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form default action is redirecting on submit..To prevent that there are several ways,

One is like below,

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "hello.txt",
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
                //console.log(result);
                $('#after').text(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And Change your:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

To:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- add the id="submit" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action of the submit button in a form is to package the data and send it over to the server ,so you must prevent that default action of the submit button .

```
   $('#target').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
      ......
    });
```